# Redirect www.domain.com/112 to www.domain.com/ using htaccess 301 redirect

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, http-status-code-301

I have thousands of URLs on my website like:

`www.domain.com/112`
and 
`www.domain.com/113`

I'd like to redirect these straight to `www.domain.com`.

Can someone explain how I do this using the 301 Redirect with htaccess?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(\d+)/?$ / [R=301,L]
```

This will redirect any digit-based request in document root to index page